# How do I have multiple separate Core Data entity types within one app

Tags: swiftui, core-data, persistence

I am creating my App mostly in Swift Playgrounds for iPad, so I am not actually using the Core Data tool on XCode. With the help of tutorials I have created a `PersistenceController` and a Data Model. When I only have one Entity type (`Club`), everything works perfectly. Now I would like to have a different, unrelated entity (`Game`). My app crashes when I try to add another `@FetchRequest` anywhere in the app, sending the error, “a FetchRequest must have an entity.” I believe this is because in my `PersistenceController` I have

```
let model = NSManagedObjectModel()
        model.entities = [clubEntity]
        //model.entities = [gameEntity]
```

I think I need `model.entities = [gameEntity]’ to fix the error mentioned above, but that will override my clubEntity no? When I include the gameEntity, I get the same error, but it appears on` @main` rather than in the ContentView. I have included all code I think may be relevant to the question, but I can add more on request.

```
import SwiftUI

@main

struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManagerModel()
    let persistanceController = PersistanceController.shared
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistanceController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(locationManager)
                .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)))
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

import CoreData

struct PersistanceController {
    static let shared = PersistanceController()
    
    static var preview: PersistanceController = {
        let result = PersistanceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
//        for index in 0..<10 {
//            
//        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        
        let clubEntity = NSEntityDescription()
        clubEntity.name = "Club"
        clubEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Club"
        
        let idAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        idAttribute.name = "id"
        idAttribute.type = .uuid
        clubEntity.properties.append(idAttribute)
        
        let nameAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        nameAttribute.name = "name"
        nameAttribute.type = .string
        clubEntity.properties.append(nameAttribute)
        
        let putterAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        putterAttribute.name = "putter"
        putterAttribute.type = .boolean
        clubEntity.properties.append(putterAttribute)
        
        let strokesNumAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        strokesNumAttribute.name = "strokes"
        strokesNumAttribute.type = .integer32
        clubEntity.properties.append(strokesNumAttribute)
        
        let strokesListAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        strokesListAttribute.name = "strokesList"
        strokesListAttribute.type = .transformable
        clubEntity.properties.append(strokesListAttribute)
        
        /////////////////////////////////
        
        let gameEntity = NSEntityDescription()
        gameEntity.name = "Game"
        gameEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Game"
        
        gameEntity.properties.append(idAttribute)
        
        gameEntity.properties.append(strokesNumAttribute)
        
        
        let model = NSManagedObjectModel()
        model.entities = [clubEntity]
        model.entities = [gameEntity]
        
        
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ClubToDo", managedObjectModel: model)
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.viewContext
            .automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {(storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Foundation

@objc(Game)
public class Game: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var strokes: Int
}

@objc(Club)
public class Club: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    //@NSManaged public var yardsNum: Int
    @NSManaged public var strokes: Int
    @NSManaged public var putter: Bool
    @NSManaged public var strokesList: [Int]
    //@NSManaged public var averageYardage: Int
    @NSManaged public var nfcTag: String
}

extension Club: Identifiable {
//    var yards: Yards{
//        get {
//            Yards(rawValue: Int(yardsNum)) ?? .normal
//        }
//        
//        set {
//            self.yardsNum = Int(newValue.rawValue)
//        }
//    }
    var strokesStandardDeviation: Double {
        guard !strokesList.isEmpty else {
            return 0.0 // or another appropriate value when the list is empty
        }
        let mean = Double(strokesList.reduce(0, +)) / Double(strokesList.count)
        let squaredDifferences = strokesList.map { pow(Double($0) - mean, 2) }
        let variance = squaredDifferences.reduce(0, +) / Double(strokesList.count)
        return sqrt(variance)
    }
    var averageYardage: Int {
        guard !strokesList.isEmpty else {
            return 0
        }
        let numStrokes = strokesList.count
        let sumArray = strokesList.reduce(0,+)
        let averageYardage = sumArray / numStrokes
        return averageYardage
    }
}
enum Yards: Int {
    case normal = 0
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import CoreData
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Club.entity(),
        sortDescriptors:[])
    private var clubs:FetchedResults<Club>
    
//    @FetchRequest(
//        entity: Game.entity(),
//        sortDescriptors:[])
//    private var games:FetchedResults<Game>
    
    @State private var shotClub = Club()
    @State private var ballClub = Club()
    @State private var showNewClub: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel
    //@State private var game = ""
    @AppStorage("NUMBER_KEY") var counter = 0
    @State var roundStarted = false
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            ClubListView(counter: $counter, roundStarted: $roundStarted)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                }
            RoundView(counter: $counter, roundStarted: $roundStarted)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "flag")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `model.entities = [clubEntity, gameEntity]` yet?

Comment: @Tom Harrington I had not but that seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model.entities` property is an array that should list all of the entities to be used in the model. As you noticed, assigning values to it twice doesn't work, because the second assignment overrides the first one. You need to list all of the entities in a single assignment, in an array of entities:

```swift
model.entities = [clubEntity, gameEntity]
```

It's pretty cool to see how you're setting up your entities in code, without using the Xcode model editor. Not many people do that, and a lot of people don't realize it's possible.